# Trying to understand: invalid operands to to binary expression, C

Tags: c

Last line yields "invalid operands to binary expression".  Trying to understand why.  Does it mean that "p2-p1" is an invalid operand to the binary expression "-" that lies to the right of p3?  Any rule I can follow here?  Confusing to me because "3-2-1" integers are valid.

```
  int array[3] = {1,2,3};
  int* p1 = &array[0];
  int* p2 = &array[1];
  int* p3 = &array[2];

  p3-p2-p1;
```

Comment: The difference between two pointers (`p3-p2`) is a `ptrdiff_t`, and you can't subtract a pointer from a `ptrdiff_t`. C11 draft standard, `6.5.6 Additive operators, Section 3 [...]For subtraction, one of the following shall hold:[...]both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible complete object types; or the left operand is a pointer to a complete object type and the right operand has integer type.[...]`.

Comment: `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are pointers to integers but not integers. But the following expression is valid: `p1 - (p2 - p3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing address arithmetic. Given operator precedence, it is evaluating `p1-p2-p3` as `(p1-p2)-p3`. `p1-p2` yields not an address but an integer. Then you are attempting to subtract an address from an integer, which isn't valid. You could do `p1-(p2-p3)`, then it's taking `p2-p3`, yielding an integer, and subtracting that as an integer offset from an address (`p1`), which will compile. However, [Thanks to @EOF for this reference in his comment] such subtraction (of integer from a pointer) would only be valid if it points somewhere within the allocation for `p1`. It's subject to the C11 standard described specifically in section 6.5.6, excerpted below:

> When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted
>   from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the
>   pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array
>   is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the
>   original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the
>   resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
>   In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an
>   array object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N
>   (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>   i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if
>   the expression P points to the last element of an array object, the
>   expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array object,
>   and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array
>   object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array
>   object. If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements
>   of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary *
>   operator that is evaluated.

Comment: thanks - makes sense. will accept soon as it allows me :)

Comment: Actually, the behavior for `p1-(p2-p3)` would be undefined in this case: `p2-p3` will be `-1`, and `&p1[-1]` doesn't point to a valid object.

Comment: @EOF interesting. `gcc` likes `p1-(p2-p3)`. Pointer minus integer should give deterministic results shouldn't it?

Comment: C11 draft standard, `6.5.6 Additive operators, Section 8: [...]If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.[...]`. Note that gcc is absolutely permitted to do what you expect, after all: `3.4.3 Section 1: undefined behavior behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,
for which this International Standard imposes no requirements.`. gcc may do whatever it likes when you do this.

Comment: @EOF OK thanks for citing that. When I get back to my pc, I'll correct my answer referencing your comment.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are all *pointers to integers*, not integers.

To get what you want, you probably want:

```
*p3 - *p2 - *p1;
```

where the `*` operator is the [*dereference operator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator). It dereferences pointers, so in this case `*p3` etc are of type `int`. You can think of it as the inverse of the `&` address-of operator.